# How to toggle disable/enable of shiro authentication?

Tags: rest, dropwizard, shiro

Is there a way to toggle on-off shiro authentication in my REST service? 
I am currently using dropwizard with shiro for my REST services?
Also how can I confirm shiro is disabled?

I also have a shiro.ini file but is there any setting that I can include to toggle shiro authentication?

```
@Override
protected ShiroConfiguration narrow(T configuration) {
    return configuration.getShiroConfiguration();
}

@Override
protected Filter createFilter(T configuration) {
    IniWebEnvironment shiroEnv = new IniWebEnvironment();
    shiroEnv.setConfigLocations(this.narrow(configuration).iniConfigs());
    shiroEnv.init();

    return new AbstractShiroFilter() {
        public void init() throws Exception {
            Collection<Realm> realms = MyShiroBundle.this.createRealms(configuration);

            DefaultWebSecurityManager webSecurityManager =
                    (DefaultWebSecurityManager)shiroEnv.getWebSecurityManager();

            if (webSecurityManager.getRealms() != null) {
                webSecurityManager.setRealms(mergeRealms(webSecurityManager.getRealms(), realms));
            } else {
                webSecurityManager.setRealms(realms);
            }

            this.setSecurityManager(webSecurityManager);
            this.setFilterChainResolver(shiroEnv.getFilterChainResolver());
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected Collection<Realm> createRealms(T configuration) {
    return mergeRealms(super.createRealms(configuration), Collections.singleton(createJdbcRealm(configuration)));
}

private static Collection<Realm> mergeRealms(Collection<Realm> realms, Collection<Realm> realms2) {
    return ImmutableList.<Realm>builder().addAll(realms).addAll(realms2).build();
}

private static Realm createJdbcRealm(ReferenceDataConfiguration configuration) {
    DataSource ds = configuration.getMyDatabaseDataSourceFactory().build(new MetricRegistry(), "my-shiro");
    JdbcRealm realm = new JdbcRealm();
    realm.setDataSource(ds);
    realm.setPermissionsLookupEnabled(false);
    realm.setCredentialsMatcher(new AllowAllCredentialsMatcher());
    realm.setAuthenticationQuery(
            "select UserId from AppUser where IsActive = 1 and UserId = ?");
    realm.setUserRolesQuery("select Role from UserRoles where UserId = ? and ValidToTime = " + VALID_TIME);
    realm.setPermissionsQuery(
            "select Permission from RolesPermissions where Role = ? and ValidToTime = " + VALID_TIME);
    return realm;
}
```

Comment: How do you add your auth to DW? I would aim for switching off auth based on a filter configuration and decouple it from actual authentication. Reason being so that you don't have to do that again if you ever decide to switch out Shiro. DW will add a filter (that you will have to extend) to do auth (usually AuthDynamicFeature through Jersey). You can simply have your switch in the registered filter and do nothing if your switch is toggled